# Dependency error when trying to install Blender on Gentoo

Tags: linux, blender, gentoo

I am trying to install Blender on gentoo using emerge, this is the error message i recieve:

```
sudo emerge --ask media-gfx/blender

 * IMPORTANT: 16 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.


 * IMPORTANT: 2 config files in '/etc/portage' need updating.
 * See the CONFIGURATION FILES and CONFIGURATION FILES UPDATE TOOLS
 * sections of the emerge man page to learn how to update config files.

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
Dependency resolution took 2.32 s.


!!! The ebuild selected to satisfy ">=media-libs/embree-3.10.0[raymask]" has unmet requirements.
- media-libs/embree-3.13.5::gentoo USE="compact-polys raymask tbb -ispc -ssp -tutorial" ABI_X86="(64)" CPU_FLAGS_X86="-avx -avx2 -avx512dq -sse2 -sse4_2"

  The following REQUIRED_USE flag constraints are unsatisfied:
    any-of ( cpu_flags_arm_neon cpu_flags_x86_sse2 cpu_flags_x86_sse4_2 cpu_flags_x86_avx cpu_flags_x86_avx2 cpu_flags_x86_avx512dq )

(dependency required by "media-gfx/blender-3.5.1-r1::gentoo[embree]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "media-gfx/blender" [argument])
```

Make.conf:

```
COMMON_FLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
ABI_X86="(64)"
CFLAGS="${COMMON_FLAGS}"
CXXFLAGS="${COMMON_FLAGS}"
FCFLAGS="${COMMON_FLAGS}"
FFLAGS="${COMMON_FLAGS}"
MAKEOPTS="-j4"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="*"
VIDEO_CARDS="nvidia"
USE="abi_x86_32 cuda bullet nvenc cycles embree ffmpeg -debug -gpm -systemd alsa  alsa-plugin -pulseaudio -gnome -kde X"
INPUT_DEVICES="libinput synaptics"
ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="~amd64"
CPU_FLAGS_X86=""
# NOTE: This stage was built with the bindist Use flag enabled

# This sets the language of build output to English.
# Please keep this setting intact when reporting bugs.
LC_MESSAGES=C.utf8

GENTOO_MIRRORS="https://mirror.clarkson.edu/gentoo/
```

Package use flags:

```
# required by media-gfx/blender-3.5.1-r1::gentoo
# required by media-gfx/blender (argument)
>=media-libs/freetype-2.13.1 brotli
# required by media-gfx/blender-3.5.1-r1::gentoo[ffmpeg]
# required by media-gfx/blender (argument)
>=media-video/ffmpeg-6.0-r1 theora opus vpx
```

I already tried adding the flags, cpu flags, updating the system, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please address the config file updates using `etc-update` or `dispatch-conf`. What profile is your system set to? `eselect profile show`. And what is available? `eselect profile list`. You might have set an architecture which Blender doesn't support but your computer probably actually does support it and you just need to tell Gentoo that.

Comment: Already adressed the config file updates, and these is my profile:
`$ eselect profile show
Current /etc/portage/make.profile symlink:
  default/linux/amd64/17.1/desktop`

`$ eselect profile list
Available profile symlink targets:
  [1]   default/linux/amd64/17.1 (stable)
  [2]   default/linux/amd64/17.1/selinux (stable)
  [3]   default/linux/amd64/17.1/hardened (stable)
  [4]   default/linux/amd64/17.1/hardened/selinux (stable)
  [5]   default/linux/amd64/17.1/desktop (stable) *`
...

Answer (score 0):

on your first error it states that you should have one of listed flag inside `CPU_FLAGS_X86`

inside your make.conf `CPU_FLAGS_X86=""`

wiki article about this variable: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/CPU_FLAGS_*

I'd suggest to use cpuid2cpuflags to get flags you'd like to put inside (it will list what your current CPU supports)